# How to customize in stock and out of stock section in Woocommerce PRODUCT CATALOG

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, customization

so everybody knows that in order to change the text for In stock and out of stock in the individual product pages you do

```
function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {

// Change In Stock Text
if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
    $availability['availability'] = __('Available!', 'woocommerce');
}
// Change Out of Stock Text
if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
    $availability['availability'] = __('Sold Out', 'woocommerce');
}
return $availability;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability', 1, 2);
```

However, in the product catalog page, where you search for products, the message doesn't change there.

What do I have to do in functions.php to change that text?

Comment: Which theme you are using?

Answer (score 0):

woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title can be changed depending where you want it placed.

Try the following function -

```
function show_product_status_catalog() {
    global $product;  
    // Change In Stock Text
    if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Available!', 'woocommerce');
    }
    // Change Out of Stock Text
    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Sold Out', 'woocommerce');
    }
    echo  $availability['availability'];
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'show_product_status_catalog' );
```